# How can I pass two parameters to a function? (react native)

Tags: react-native

By this codes, I can pass a `key` to my function and use that. Now How can I pass a `key` and another value like `quantity`?

```
deleteItem(key){
  consol.log(key);
}

<ListView style={{zIndex:1}}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      enableEmptySections={true}
        renderRow={ (rowData)=>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.deleteItem.bind(this, rowData.key)}>
   <Text>Delete this row</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

}/>
```

I need to pass `rowData.quantity` inside `rowData.key`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding in the JSX, do it in your constructor instead, then your delete method you can define the arguments you expect like so

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
}

deleteItem(quantity, key){
  consol.log(key);
}

<ListView style={{zIndex:1}}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      enableEmptySections={true}
        renderRow={ (rowData)=>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.deleteItem(rowData.quantity,rowData.key)}>
   <Text>Delete this row</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

}/>
```

However, I would also like to address that both the properties you are passing belong to the same object, so you could just pass the object in on its own and destructure those values out of it.

Comment: Without constructor: onPress={this.deleteItem.bind(this,rowData.quantity,rowData.key)}