# how to pass input values to a funtion in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 2 inputs `email` and `name` which has `default values`. I am trying to pass the values to a function called `getalldata`. Every time I console.log(), I get undefined as result. I am new to native so pls help.

```
export default function Signupfor(props) {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState();


  function getAlldata() {
 
    console.log(name,email);
  
  }

  const {userInfo, log} = props?.route?.params;
  console.log(log.name);
  return (
    <View style={styles.prheight}>
      <View style={styles.form}>
    
       
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={newText => setName(userInfo.user.name)}
          style={styles.input}
          label="Name"
          defaultValue={userInfo.user.name}
         />
         <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          label="Email"
          defaultValue={userInfo.user.email}
          onChangeText={newText => setEmail(userInfo.user.name)}
        />
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Button
          title="Lets Go"
          type="submit"
          onPress={() => getAlldata()}
        />
      </View>
```

Comment: you can check the following link : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271094/how-can-i-pass-two-parameters-to-a-function-react-native

Comment: Can you try changing  onChangeText={setName} and  onChangeText={setEmail}

Comment: @Azzy  defaultValue={userInfo.user.email} is not displaying the value

Comment: @menucd I dint get you, you want to display the default value, or show the updated values, if you want to also include the default value then try setting it in  `useState(userInfo.user.name)`

Comment: i want to display userInfo.user.name in the input fild when the page is loded and pass the data to  getAlldata() when i click the submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on changeText will only run when you input/change something in input

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
    
    const {userInfo, log} = props?.route?.params;
    
     setEmail(userInfo?.email)
    setName(userInfo?.name)
    
    },[props?.route?.params])
```

and int render method

```
<TextInput
          onChangeText={newText => setName(newText)}
          style={styles.input}
          label="Name"
          defaultValue={userInfo.user.name}
         />
         <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          label="Email"
          defaultValue={userInfo.user.email}
          onChangeText={newText => setEmail(newText)}
        />
```

Comment: when i do console.log(email,name)  inside getAlldata() i am getting undefined

Comment: ragnar are u missing something?

Comment: i did setEmail(userInfo.user.name) and it got fixed

Answer (score 1):

you can set value as default also

const {userInfo, log} = props?.route?.params;

const [email, setEmail] = useState(userInfo.user.email);
const [name, setName] = useState(userInfo.user.name);

```
<TextInput
      onChangeText={newText => setName(userInfo.user.name)}
      style={styles.input}
      label="Name"
      value={name}
      defaultValue={userInfo.user.name}
     />
     <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      label="Email"
      value={email}
      defaultValue={userInfo.user.email}
      onChangeText={newText => setEmail(userInfo.user.name)}
    />
```